# Livewire3: array property gets reset in method (but seems to be ok in the view)

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have component with following property and method (action):

```
public array $selectedVariantOption = [];

public function selectVariantOption(int $variantId, int $variantOptionId) {

    $this->selectedVariantOption[$variantId] = $variantOptionId;
    dump($this->selectedVariantOption); // array gets reset here - only recently inserted value is present.
}
```

When I call `wire:click="selectVariantOption(..., ...)"` dump shows an array with only lastly inserted value.
However, when I render the array in blade view, it displays correctly - with all previously inserted values.

Can anyone help me with this?